# Java 2D Terrain Generation Using Seeds

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am trying to make a 2D game in LWJGL. I am having a problem with terrain generation.
 I currently have an algorithm to generate terrain but it is always random and I can never get that same world again I would like to make an algorithm that generates a x and y coordinates based on a given number.

My current world generation looks like this:

```
     final float STEP_MAX = 1f;
     final float STEP_CHANGE = 1;
     final int HEIGHT_MAX = 100;

     double height = HEIGHT_MAX;
     double slope = STEP_MAX;

     for (int x = -WORLDSIZE; x < WORLDSIZE; x++) {
          height += slope;
          slope += (Math.random() * STEP_CHANGE) * 2 - STEP_CHANGE;

          if (slope > STEP_MAX)  slope = STEP_MAX;
          if (slope < -STEP_MAX) slope = -STEP_MAX;

          if (height > HEIGHT_MAX) { 
              height = HEIGHT_MAX;
              slope *= -1;
          }
          if (height < 0) { 
              height = 0;
              slope *= -1;
          }
          Tile newTile = new Tile(x*25,(int)height*25,25,25,TileType.Grass);
          tiles.add(newTile);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `Random` takes a seed that will result in the same sequence every time.

Comment: What do you mean by random takes a seed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create your random number generator yourself (rather than letting Math.random() do so for you), you can specify a seed:

```
Random random = new Random(yourSeed);
random.nextDouble();
```

the `Random` class also has many useful methods you might want to look at.

More info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html